# React Native promise pass the value to variable as string

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, es6-promise

I am new to React Native. I have to create a promise and be able to get the response data.

```
export async function findColor() {
    
        try{
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
            const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');

            const resp = (
                await api(token).get(`api/blockgroup/getList`)
            ).data;
           
            const retVal = '"' + resp.data[0].template.mcolor +'"';
            
            console.log (typeof retVal, retVal, 'retvalue');
       
            return retVal;
        }
        catch(err){
            return {
                error: true,
                code: err.request.status,
            };
        }
    }
```

But when I called the function I get something like this

> {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

I found out that I can access the value by using `.then()` as I tried to printout the value to console:

```
findColor().then(response => console.log(response));
```

I got the string value

> "#0eade1"

But I don't know how can I pass the value to a variable as a string? Let's say I want to create a variable `color` and pass the value `"#0eade1"` to it. How can I do that?

I really appreciate if anyone can help me. Thanks!

EDIT:
i just want to make this clear. i need to pass the value only as string because i need to pass it to another module from import. i have config module where i need to change my theme color with the value from hook i called. thats config will only accept string object, and i don't know if i should use react native component in config module.

Comment: An [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) always returns a promise. So you must use [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), or [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the value. `const color = await findColor()`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a hook that handles that. Consider the following snippet.

```js
export function useColor() {
    const [color, setColor] = useState()

    React.useEffect(() => {

        // you should add your function in here
        findColor().then(response => setColor(response))

    }, [])
    
    return {
        color,
    }
}
```

Then use your hook in your screen, whenever you need `color`.

```js
const TestScreen = () => {

    // color can used however you like
    const {color} = useColor()
}
```

**Edit:** Judging from the comments you are using a class component which does not allow the use of hooks. We can still do the same.

```js
constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.state  =   {
       color : "",
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    findColor().then(response => this.setState({color: response}))
}

render() {
   return <Text>this.state.color</Text>
}
```

Comment: i tried to use useState and useEffect before but i got error 'Invalid Hook call, Hook can only be called inside the body of function component'

Comment: Yes, hooks are only valid inside functional components of course. If you are using a class component, then this approach is not possible.

Comment: yeah, i just want to create a simple function that return hook as string, and call that function then pass the return value to a variable. use that variable to change my config module.

Comment: You need a state to achieve this, since everything is async. If you are using a class component, then you need to do the same as in my answer but not with hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this by this you can use this as normal function call.

```
export async function findColor() {
            const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
            const id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id');
            api(token).get(`api/blockgroup/getList`)
            .then(resp=>{
              const retVal = '"' + resp.data[0].template.mcolor +'"';
            
              console.log (typeof retVal, retVal, 'retvalue');
       
              return retVal;
            });
            .catch((err){
            return {
                error: true,
                code: err.request.status,
            };
        })
    }
```

Comment: this still return a promise object when i tried to call it as normal function. still get ```{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}``` as response